# Can we have oneboxed links for scientific papers in chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, hyperlinks

Certain weblinks when posted in chat will [onebox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57287/312026), i.e. they will be displayed as a box containing part of the content of the site linked. This is especially cool for SE questions and answers but also for Wikipedia.

Here at chemistry.SE, we often discuss some cool research or direct each other to interesting journal articles. The most common would probably be articles published in Wiley-VCH journals (prominently including the *Angewandte Chemie),* Journals hosted on Sciencedirect *(Tetrahedron* jumping to mind but that’s by far not alone) and those published by the American Chemical Society (prominently including their flagship *JACS).*

Since all of these follow a rather systematic link syntax and include an abstract on the page you will be linked to (sometimes the article’s first page as a PDF, but if there is no official abstract, I’m sure you can figure something out), it would be great if these also got oneboxed.

Would it be possible to make it happen?

Comment: Oneboxing stuff is a site-wide thing, as such it should probably go on meta.SE, although I'm not sure if it would be a very high priority for the devs. That said Chemobot is supposed to be able to pick up on DOI numbers, but it seems to be buggy at the moment.

Comment: I suspect that this would have to be specific for each publisher, and I suspect that this will make it too much effort to implement for SE.

Comment: @MadScientist I attempted to reduce the complexity by restricting it to Wiley, Sciencedirect and ACS.

Comment: I personally would rather like to be able to turn off one-boxing completely and rather have only the title of the page shown, i.e. in the format `[...](htt...)`. That being said, Hippalectryon tried to implement short cuts to `!!doi/DOI` and `!!scholar/search` to make accessing such things easier.